# KendoUI Responsive Panel - Fixed Header and Sidebar when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a layout using a fixed header and sidebar (when visible/active) that does not disappear when scrolling, hope the http://jsfiddle.net/goltech/tfx1j6uh/ explains it better?  Using the KendoUI ReponsivePanel and the demo from Kendo website. Thanking You

```
#sidebar {
        /* panel background should be set to match design */
        background: #092646;
    }
    article {
        /* clear the floating sidebar */
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    header {
        padding: 1em;
        color: #fff;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #014F80 0%, #092646 100%);
    }
    h1 {
        display: inline;
    }
    p {
        padding: 2em;
    }
    nav a {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background: #ddd;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: .5em;
    }
```